# Как заставить программу добавлять 1% к каждому месяцу

Tags: c

Хочу сделать программу которая будет принимать начальную сумму и добавлять 1 процент к 1 месяцу. И делать это столько раз сколько пользователь ввёл месяцев!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    float start_number,month,x,i;
    printf("Give start number: ",start_number);
    scanf("%f",&start_number);
    printf("Give number of month: ",month);
    scanf("%f",&month);
    i = 0;
    do
    {
      x=((start_number/100)+start_number); i++;
        printf("%f\n",x);
    }
    while (i < month);
    return 0;
}
```

Система должна получиться такая:
к начальной сумме например 100 добавляем 1%
Получаем 101 и к сумме 101 добавляем 1%
И таких повторений должно быть столько сколько месяцев ввели

Comment: Не работает, требую больше информации

Comment: блин ну да не то написал. pow(1.01,monts)*n надо.

Comment: так добавлять к месяцу или к сумме?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

без циклов с math.h функцией pow. собирать с ключом -lm.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    float start_number,month;
    printf("Give start number: ",start_number);
    scanf("%f",&start_number);
    printf("Give number of month: ",month);
    scanf("%f",&month);

    printf("result is: %f\n", pow(1.01,month)*start_number);
}
```

Comment: Если я верно понял, ТС хотел выводить данные ежемесячно?..

Comment: Ну в самом тексте вопроса нет про необходимость вывода промежуточных результатов.

Comment: Ну, я именно так воспринял его "*делать это столько раз сколько пользователь ввёл месяцев*" и вывод значений в цикле...

Comment: Насчёт того вывода в цикле - вполне может быть, что он просто для проверки добавлен был. Вообще была бы очень странная программа, которая без каких-то пояснений выводит просто значения каждой итерации.

Comment: Ну, я просто высказал свое мнение, не более того. Раз ТС ответ принял, то и вопроса по сути нет...